# How do you get the bar widths to be even, and apply the suggested fix to my data?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a bar graph but the bars are not an even size. How do we make them a uniform width? I have looked at the recommended answers but thy have not solve the issue. In addition, I could not get one of the recommended 'fixes' to work.

This is my data....

```
structure(list(Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
                                                                                          "Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), shoot = c(0.37, 0.43, 0.52, 
                                                                                                                                       0.33, 1.24, 1.12, 1.28, 1.28, 0.48, 0.95, 1.35, 0.95, 1.37, 1.4, 
                                                                                                                                       1.39, 1.34, 0.67, 0.8, 1.13, 0.32, 1.34, 1.53, 1.25, 1.4, 0.58, 
                                                                                                                                       0.98, 1.46, 0.69, 1.44, 1.83, 1.65, 1.71, 1, 1.17, 1.45, 0.98, 
                                                                                                                                       1.52, 1.75, 1.63, 1.7, 0.25, 0.24, 0.91, 1.17, 1.23, 1.22, 1.26, 
                                                                                                                                       0.89, 1.54, 1.01, 1.48, 0.93, 1.2, 1.55, 1.4, 1.19, 0.9, 1.29, 
                                                                                                                                       1.43, 1.31, 1.75, 1.92, 1.63, 1.64, 1.31, 1.43, 1.77, 1.28, 1.34, 
                                                                                                                                       1.54, 1.66, 1.88, 1.29, 1.05, 1.63, 1.36, 1.9, 2.18, 2.03, 1.68, 
                                                                                                                                       1.36, 1.16, 1.77, 1.35, 0.9, 1.49, 1.41, 1.57, 1.39, 1.22, 1.39, 
                                                                                                                                       1.37, 0.94, 1.83, 1.6, 0.24, 1.71, 1.67, 1.44, 1.9, 1.98, 2.04, 
                                                                                                                                       1.64, 1.71, 1.08, 1.89, 1.19, 1.58, 1.97, 1.97, 1.87, 2.21, 1.68, 
                                                                                                                                       2, 1.75, 1.24, 2.1, 2.25, 2.1, 2.24, 0.88, 0.72, 0.3, 0.58, 1.23, 
                                                                                                                                       1.32, 1.47, 1.54, 0.4, 0.47, 0.82, 1.2, 1.38, 1.09, 1.41, 0.23, 
                                                                                                                                       0.57, 0.84, 0.54, 1.29, 1.23, 1.14, 1.63, 1.61, 0.48, 0.95, 1.01, 
                                                                                                                                       0.8, 1.42, 1.12, 1.74, 1.89, 1.58, 1.6, 0.35, 1.38, 1.4, 1.58, 
                                                                                                                                       1.71, 1.64), herb.dmg.11.DEC = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 160L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here is my code for the plot....

```
library(Rmisc) library(ggplot2)
tg5 <- summarySE(q, measurevar="shoot", groupvars=c("herb.dmg.11.DEC"  ,"Waterlogging"))
ggplot(tg5, aes( x = as.factor(herb.dmg.11.DEC), y = shoot, fill = Waterlogging))+
theme_bw()+geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6, position = "dodge",colour="black")+
geom_errorbar((aes(ymin = shoot-se, ymax = shoot+se)), size = 0.3, 
width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(.6))
```

Here is the initial plot....

[Uneven bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH3L6.png)

Here is my attempt to fix the issue......

```
ggplot(tg5, aes( x = as.factor(herb.dmg.11.DEC), y = shoot, fill = Waterlogging))+theme_bw()+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"),colour="black")+
geom_errorbar((aes(ymin = shoot-se, ymax = shoot+se,width=0.4)),
position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

[attempt to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeeVn.png)

but as you can see in the attempted fix, the error bars are not placed evenly, and the bars for 3 and 4 are not in a symmetrical position with the other bars....

There was one answer that I could not apply to my data which changes the data frame....

```
dat <- data.frame(a=rep(LETTERS[1:3],3),
              b=rep(letters[1:3],each=3),
              v=1:9)[-2,]
ggplot(dat, aes(x=a, y=v, colour=b)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=b), stat="identity", position="dodge")
dat.all <- rbind(dat, cbind(expand.grid(a=levels(dat$a), b=levels(dat$b)), v=NA))
ggplot(dat.all, aes(x=a, y=v, colour=b)) +geom_bar(aes(fill=b), stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Can anyone please offer some help to apply this final solution or any other one?

Comment: I tried to create the new data frame: dat.all <- rbind(tg5, cbind(expand.grid(herb.dmg.11.DEC=levels(tg5$herb.dmg.11.DEC), Waterrlogging=levels(tg5$Watterlogging)), shoot=NA)) but got the following error message: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get `summarySE` to work on my R session, but you can get statistics on your dataframe using `dplyr`.

But first, you need to expand your dataset by doing:

```
df2 <- rbind(df,cbind(expand.grid(Waterlogging = levels(df$Waterlogging), herb.dmg.11.DEC = levels(as.factor(df$herb.dmg.11.DEC)), shoot = NA)))
```

Then, you can use `dplyr` to calculate the mean and SE of your dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(Waterlogging, herb.dmg.11.DEC) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(shoot, na.rm = TRUE), SD = sd(shoot, na.rm = TRUE), Count = n()) %>%
  mutate(SE = SD/sqrt(Count))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   Waterlogging [2]
   Waterlogging    herb.dmg.11.DEC    Mean     SD Count      SE
   <fct>           <chr>             <dbl>  <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1 Non-waterlogged 0                 1.47   0.378    69  0.0455
 2 Non-waterlogged 1                 1.79   0.250    10  0.0792
 3 Non-waterlogged 2                 1.9    0.195     4  0.0976
 4 Non-waterlogged 3               NaN     NA         1 NA     
 5 Non-waterlogged 4               NaN     NA         1 NA     
 6 Waterlogged     0                 1.40   0.187    10  0.0591
 7 Waterlogged     1                 1.39   0.347    14  0.0928
 8 Waterlogged     2                 1.20   0.488    18  0.115 
 9 Waterlogged     3                 1.05   0.463    18  0.109 
10 Waterlogged     4                 0.758  0.324    25  0.0648
```

and you can plot it by doing:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2,aes(x = herb.dmg.11.DEC, y = Mean, fill = Waterlogging)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean-SE, ymax = Mean+SE),size = 0.3, 
                width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I try and run df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(Waterlogging, herb.dmg.11.DEC) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(shoot, na.rm = TRUE), SD = sd(shoot, na.rm = TRUE), Count = n()) %>%
  mutate(SE = SD/sqrt(Count)) I get this error..... Error in df2 %>% group_by(Waterlogging, herb.dmg.11.DEC) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(shoot,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Because you have to load first the `dplyr` package by doing `library(dplyr)`. If you have an error saying that this package does not exist, you have to install it using `install.packages("dplyr")`.

Comment: In order to get summarySE to work, one needs to include na.rm = TRUE into the script, which tells it to ignore NA's. e.g. tg5 <- summarySE(df2, measurevar="shoot", groupvars=c("herb.dmg.11.DEC"  ,"Waterlogging"),na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: Good to know thanks ;). So, does my answer works for you ? do you solve the issue with `dplyr` ?

Comment: I have installed the package, but still get this error message....Error in mean(shoot, na.rm = TRUE) : object 'shoot' not found. Not sure what the issue is? ANy way I got it to work with summarySE. Thank you for the assistance!  On a side note, I tried to make the df2 object with the mother data set that had many more columns than the one I uploaded here. Yet I got the error message: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match. I though we were pulling out the factors by using the $ sign, so im not sure why its telling me the columns don't match...

Comment: Probably the structure of your mother dataset is different and does not have the same amount of column. Glad my answer was (somehow) able to help you.